# flutter application get crash on start up on android 4.4.2(API 19)

Tags: dart, flutter, android-4.4-kitkat

My flutter app get crash on **android 4.4.2** on startup 
and this is the log

I've tried to remove the firebase from the application put it still get crash

This is the log that I get after running

---

> 04-11 11:23:39.709 4391-4391/com.brain_socket.almadar E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main 
>     Process:
>   com.brain_socket.almadar, PID: 4391
>   
>     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get
>   provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.brain_socket.almadar-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.brain_socket.almadar-1,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>   
>         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4793)
>   
>         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4385)
>   
>         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4325)
>   
>         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
>   
>         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
>   
>         at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   
>         at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>   
>         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>   
>         at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   
>         at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   
>         at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>   
>         at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>   
>         at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   
>         Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.brain_socket.almadar-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.brain_socket.almadar-1,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>   
>         at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>   
>         at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
>   
>         at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
>   
>         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4778)
>   
>         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4385)
>   
>         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4325)
>   
>         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135) 
>   
>         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
>   
>         at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>   
>         at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>   
>         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
>   
>         at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>   
>         at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>   
>         at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>   
>         at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
>   
>         at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Manifest file :

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
>
> <application
>     android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
>     android:label="Holidays"
>     android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
>     <activity
>         android:name=".MainActivity"
>         android:launchMode="singleTop"
>         android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
>         android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density"
>         android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
>         android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
>         <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
>              until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
>              there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
>              defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
>         <meta-data
>             android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
>             android:value="true" />
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
>     <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
>         android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
>
>     <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
>         android:configChanges=
>             "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
>         />
>
>     <activity
>         android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
>         android:exported="true">
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
>             <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
> </application> </manifest>
> ```

Comment: You should describe how you added firebase and what code you have

Comment: I'm using firebase_messaging plugin and i followed the same tips in the documentation of firebase , and it works fine in other devices that have more the 19 API

Comment: Can you post your AndroidManifest.xml file ?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad I've added it to the question